# how can i resize a jscrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

Ok so I have this code:

```
//adding the panel which will hold the order table
JPanel orderPanel = new JPanel();
right.add(orderPanel);
JTable order = new JTable(orderData, orderColumnNames);
JScrollPane orderPane = new JScrollPane(order);
orderPanel.add(orderPane);
```

And I want to be able to remove this space :

[image: The description of what I want to remove]

I guess the space is made by the JScrollPane but i can't find any method to resize the JScrollPane to the JTable's size

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213645/set-size-of-jtable-in-jscrollpane-and-in-jpanel-with-the-size-of-the-jframe and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234530/problems-with-jtable-and-jscrollpane-size ?

Comment: ty nikis i wanted to do it without setprefferedsize but apparently i need to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the reasons adduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), don't of invoke `setPreferredSize()`. Instead, override [`getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28%29) to return the desired size.