# Adding a scroll pane to GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

I am trying to add two scroll pane along with one label and one button in a JPanel using GridBagLayout. While the first scroll pane containing a JList and the second scroll pane containing a JTable. Below is the code:

```
    JPanel capabilityPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    JScrollPane capabilityScrollPane = new JScrollPane(cbList,
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);


    JScrollPane capabilityTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table,
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save Table Values");

    JLabel capabilityLabel = new JLabel("Boolean Capability List");
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    capabilityPanel.add(capabilityLabel, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    capabilityPanel.add(capabilityScrollPane,constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    capabilityPanel.add(saveButton, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    capabilityPanel.add(capabilityTableScrollPane, constraints);
```

The problem is when I am directly adding the table in the panel instead of the corresponding scroll pane, it is displaying properly on the screen. But when I am adding the scroll pane, only three element is displayed, table is not showing at all. I want the table to be shown with scroll.

Can you please help me with this situation?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21943545/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will create one outerpanel 
two inner panel
One for list
One for table
**Layout**

[image: Layout Structure]

package newpackage;

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    outerPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    listPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
    tablePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    outerPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    jLabel1.setText("Boolean Capability List");

    jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
        String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", " " };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout listPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(listPanel);
    listPanel.setLayout(listPanelLayout);
    listPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        listPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(listPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(0, 177, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
    );
    listPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        listPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(listPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    outerPanel.add(listPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);

    jButton1.setText("Save Values");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout tablePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(tablePanel);
    tablePanel.setLayout(tablePanelLayout);
    tablePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        tablePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(tablePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 303, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(tablePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(101, 101, 101)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    tablePanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        tablePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(tablePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 201, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    outerPanel.add(tablePanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    getContentPane().add(outerPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JList jList1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
private javax.swing.JPanel listPanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel outerPanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel tablePanel;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Output**

[image: Final Output]

Comment: fantastic Madhan! Works great ! Just one question. Is it possible to place the outerPanel inside another panel vertically? Actually I have to place this setting ( label, two scroll pane, button) below one textatea, which is already inside a panel. Now when I am adding the outerPanel into the already existing panel, the outerPanel taking up the whole space and my text area is not visible.

Comment: I suggest you to use Netbeans because it is easy to design your layout via simple drag and drop.And go throught different layouts in java on how to use them

Comment: I was using netbeans only, but did't know this feature. thanks again !